# Different formulations of Gauss's lemma

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

This may be a somewhat dumb question, but I have recently learned of Gauss's lemma, from 2 different books, that give 2 different formulations and I must be having some kind of mental block, because I can't figure out how they are equivalent.

The first formulation is:

> Let $f$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ be the product of two monic (or equivalently of content $0$, if I understand this correctly) polynomials $g$ and $h$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$. Then $g$ and $h$ themselves are members of $\Bbb Z[x]$.

The second formulation is:

> Let $f$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ be irreducible over $\Bbb Z$. Then $f$, considered as a member of $\Bbb Q[x]$, is also irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Can someone please point out to me how exactly these two statements are equivalent? I feel like they're contrapositives of each other, but straight up negating and flipping either doesn't produce the other...

Edit: So just to clarify what I'm having trouble with, the contrapositive of the second statement should, in my opinion, be "If $f$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$, then it's reducible over $\Bbb Z$". But who's to say that the factors of $f$ over $\Bbb Z$ will be the same as over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: I removed "definition" from the original question; there are no definitions here, only statements. Anyway, I think you are on the right track; the second statement is the contrapositive of the first, after unpacking the definition of "irreducible over $\mathbb Q$".

Comment: I noticed your edit, thank you for that. I was actually trying to remember what the appropriate word would be ("formulation"), but since I couldn't I went with "definition". Regarding the question itself, I can feel that I'm on the right track, but I'm still having trouble producing one formulation from the other...

Comment: Try thinking this way. Every time a integer polynomial splits into a product of rational polynomials, it splits into the product of integer polynomials. This is the first formulation. On the other hand, the second formulation is: if a polynomial cannot split into integer factors, it cannot split into rational also. The two formulations are the same; one with "can", the other with "cannot", but they describe the same phenomenon.

Comment: Oh, finally I see what you mean. You are saying that the first statement is **stronger** than the second. Strictly speaking you are right. However, the first statement also has a stronger assumption: the two polynomials are monic.